# Using an Event Change as Treatment in a Regression

Tags: regression, causality, treatment-effect

This is probably a fairly simple question, but it is one that I have not considered until now.

Imagine that I have some $Y$ of interest (let's say, body fat percentage), and I also have some $X$ of interest - a binary indicator of whether or not a person has changed their eating habit to a particular diet (for simplicity's sake, let's assume that this diet is a -500 caloric deficit diet). Again, for simplicity's sake, assume that I have identified the sufficient adjustment set so that unobserved confounding is not an issue in this hypothetical example.

At first glance, the solution seems simple if I want to determine the effect of a change to $X$:

$Y$ = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1{X}$ + $\beta_2{Z_1}$ + $\beta_3{Z_2}$ + ...

Say that I compute the marginal effect of moving from $X$ = 0 to $X$ = 1 and that this is the effect of interest. Is there not a problem here? For example, (given that $X$ = 1 denotes a *change* in diet), values of $X$ = 0 could be individuals who have *never* been on a -500 caloric deficit diet *or* individuals who *have already been* on the diet before observation for this study. These are two very different groups who are in the reference category for very different reasons. Does this matter? Is there a very simple fix for this beyond changing the definition of $X$ (perhaps it would be easier to measure $X$ as whether an individual is simply on the diet, but perhaps this question is of less interest than the change *to* the diet).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this other than changing the definition of X. But that seems pretty simple, at least, methodologically.  Substantively, you have to decide what you want. Given the example, which is pretty easy to understand and doesn't seem to require a lot of substantive knowledge, my inclination would be to have X be a four level categorical variable: 1) On-On 2) On-Off, 3) Off-On and 4) Off-Off.

Of course, if you have more data (like time on the diet and time off the diet) you could try to incorporate that. But I'm just going on what you clearly have.